# How to Transfer input Data to another Data using next.js 12

Tags: next.js

this is my index code and I want to transfer / send this data to another page
I try this code but it's not working I don't why

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
function index() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const handleImgInput = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push({
      pathname: "/createproject/uploadnfts/nftdetails",
      query: inputValue,
    });
  };
  return (
    <form action="" onSubmit={handleImgInput}>
      <input
        type="email"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

this is the data page code. when this page open, I didn't receive the input value from my index page and also what i input in the index file, it appears to my localhost link like this:
http://localhost:3001/data?demo@gmail.com

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

function Data() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    query: { inputValue },
  } = router;
  const props = {
    inputValue,
  };
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{inputValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query property in the router options requires passing an object to it. The query params are formed from the key-value pairs in the object.

See below example from the Next.js docs:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function ReadMore({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        router.push({
          pathname: '/post/[pid]',
          query: { pid: post.id },
        })
      }}
    >
      Click here to read more
    </button>
  )
}
```

> Taken from: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#with-url-object

In your case, this would be something like:

```
const handleImgInput = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push({
      pathname: "/createproject/uploadnfts/nftdetails",
      query: { value: inputValue },
    });
};
```

When you want to access the query params, make sure to reference them like an object's properties. For the example above, this would be:

```
const { value } = router.query;
```

Comment: I also try it but It's not working

Comment: I updated the answer to include the proper way of accessing the query params

Comment: it's working but one problem I'm facing is, all the data that submit, also add to the url, so how do clean the url, I mean remove the extra things from url

Comment: It's called URL Encoding. You have to encode specific illegal characters in the URL to satisfy the legal ASCII characters allowed to be part of the URL. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding. To decode your value, you can use decodeURI() in JS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

Comment: I upload a image , create url  and store the image value a state and then pass this state and try to show it another and what exactly happend, i can show but the image  src also includee to the src. but the image source length is too big and it's cover the whole url, I even don't understand my page url

Comment: I mean, it's hard for me to help you with that, I just answered your question here relating to Next.js